# WCF self-hosted service SSL/transport security/Basic authentication doesn't ask for credentials

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, wshttpbinding, self-hosting

I've created a self-hosted WCF service with HTTPS/SSL, transport security and Basic authentication. For some reason, when I run the service in the browser it never asks for credentials. What's wrong?

Service configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsHttpTest.GreetingServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WsHttpTest.GreetingServiceBehavior" name="WsHttpTest.GreetingService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8555/WsHttpTest/Greeting" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="WsHttpTest.IGreetingService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

HTTP config:

```
C:\>httpcfg query ssl
    IP                      : 0.0.0.0:8555
    Hash                    : 14ae237add3c49 a5091367487563cf6f6a8f586
    Guid                    : {9416496a-6d3e-4680-a9d1-03defd97d7d6}
    CertStoreName           : MY
    CertCheckMode           : 0
    RevocationFreshnessTime : 0
    UrlRetrievalTimeout     : 0
    SslCtlIdentifier        :
    SslCtlStoreName         :
    Flags                   : 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\>httpcfg query urlacl
    URL : https://localhost:8555/WsHttpTest/Greeting/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration of `wsHttpBinding` is used only if you communicate with the endpoint = you create the proxy and call operation exposed on service contract. When opening the service's help page you don't communicate with the endpoint.

`ServiceMetadataBehavior` also offers two additional properties `HttpsHelpPageBinding` and `HttpsHelpPageBindingConfiguration`. Perhaps if you play with these properties and configure some custom binding (must be custom because it requires `MessageVersion.None`) for them you will be able to force help page to require authentication as well but I have never tried it.

I would start with something like:

```
<bindings>
  <cutstomBinding>
    <binding name="helpPage">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="None" />
      <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```